# Какой способ проверки "является ли объект экземпляром класса" быстрее?

Tags: java, классы

Какой из этих двух способов производительнее(быстрее)?
1 способ:

```
if (!(o instanceof Test)) return false;
```

2 способ:

```
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
```

Comment: Не совсем корректный вопрос. getClass() делает не тоже самое, что и instanceof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный вопрос.
Oчевидно, что способ `getClass() != o.getClass()` будет работать быстрее, чем `instanceof`, т.к. это только лишь сравнение ссылок.

Но эти два способа, в некоторых ситуациях, не эквиваленты между собой.
Приведу пример:

```
class Type{}

SubType extends Type{}
```

Если мы напишим:

```
Type type = new SubType()
  if(type instanceof Type)
       System.out.pritln("it's working!")
  if(type.getClass() == Type.class)
       System.out.pritln("it is not working!")
```

Первая проверка выполнится, а вторая нет.

Теперь попробуем разобраться как реализована конструкция `instanceof`.
При компиляции она пребразуется в специальный для нее байткод инструкцию [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof) . 
Заглянем в [исходники hotspot](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/hs/) и посмотрим, как она генерируется в assembler код. Будет смотреть **только для архитектуры x86**.

Находим место, где обрабатывается `intanceof` **jit компилятором**:

*src/hotspot/cpu/x86/c1_LIRAssembler_x86.cpp::emit_opTypeCheck*

```
...
} else
 if (code == lir_instanceof) {
    Register obj = op->object()->as_register();
    Register dst = op->result_opr()->as_register();
    Label success, failure, done;
    emit_typecheck_helper(op, &success, &failure, &failure);
    ...
  }
...
```

*src/hotspot/cpu/x86/c1_LIRAssembler_x86.cpp::emit_typecheck_helper*

```
...
} else {
  // perform the fast part of the checking logic
  __ check_klass_subtype_fast_path(klass_RInfo, k_RInfo, Rtmp1, success_target, failure_target, NULL);
  // call out-of-line instance of __ check_klass_subtype_slow_path(...):
  __ push(klass_RInfo);
  __ push(k_RInfo);
  __ call(RuntimeAddress(Runtime1::entry_for(Runtime1::slow_subtype_check_id)));
  __ pop(klass_RInfo);
  __ pop(k_RInfo);
  // result is a boolean
  __ cmpl(k_RInfo, 0);
  __ jcc(Assembler::equal, *failure_target);
  // successful cast, fall through to profile or jump
}
....
```

Здесь мы можем видеть две проверки **check_klass_subtype_fast_path** и **check_klass_subtype_slow_path**.
Во время работы программы **jvm** собирает некоторую информацию и статистику. Например, она может сохранять результаты предыдущих выполений `instanceof` и на основе этого делать предположения о типе. Более подробно об этом можно прочитать [здесь](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/TypeProfile) . 
Быстрая проверка основывается на этой оптимизации и она не всегда может выполняться успешно, тогда вступает в дело более медленная **check_klass_subtype_slow_path** .

Для дальнейшего понимания, следует немного рассказать про класс *src/hotspot/share/oops/klass.cpp* . 
В нем содержится информация (барабанная дробь) о классе. Там есть много интересных полей, но нас интересует следующее:

```
 // The fields _super_check_offset, _secondary_super_cache, _secondary_supers
 // and _primary_supers all help make fast subtype checks.  See big discussion
 // in doc/server_compiler/checktype.txt
 // Where to look to observe a supertype (it is &_secondary_super_cache for
 // secondary supers, else is &_primary_supers[depth()].
 juint       _super_check_offset;
 // Cache of last observed secondary supertype
 Klass*      _secondary_super_cache;
 // Array of all secondary supertypes
 Array<Klass*>* _secondary_supers;
 // Ordered list of all primary supertypes
 Klass*      _primary_supers[_primary_super_limit];
```

Видно, что в нем содержится массив со всеми родительскими типами, так же есть несколько полей *для быстрой проверки типов* .

Не будем рассматривать метод:

*src/hotspot/cpu/x86/macroAssembler_x86.cpp::check_klass_subtype_fast_path*

Там происходит лишь проверка закэшированных значений с проверяемым типом.
Гораздо интереснее метод **check_klass_subtype_slow_path**

```
...
Label L_fallthrough;
int label_nulls = 0;
if (L_success == NULL)   { L_success   = &L_fallthrough; label_nulls++; }
if (L_failure == NULL)   { L_failure   = &L_fallthrough; label_nulls++; }

// a couple of useful fields in sub_klass:
int ss_offset = in_bytes(Klass::secondary_supers_offset());
int sc_offset = in_bytes(Klass::secondary_super_cache_offset());
Address secondary_supers_addr(sub_klass, ss_offset);
Address super_cache_addr(     sub_klass, sc_offset);

// Do a linear scan of the secondary super-klass chain.
// This code is rarely used, so simplicity is a virtue here.
// The repne_scan instruction uses fixed registers, which we must spill.
// Don't worry too much about pre-existing connections with the input regs.

assert(sub_klass != rax, "killed reg"); // killed by mov(rax, super)
assert(sub_klass != rcx, "killed reg"); // killed by lea(rcx, &pst_counter)

// Get super_klass value into rax (even if it was in rdi or rcx).
bool pushed_rax = false, pushed_rcx = false, pushed_rdi = false;
if (super_klass != rax || UseCompressedOops) {
  if (!IS_A_TEMP(rax)) { push(rax); pushed_rax = true; }
  mov(rax, super_klass);
}
if (!IS_A_TEMP(rcx)) { push(rcx); pushed_rcx = true; }
if (!IS_A_TEMP(rdi)) { push(rdi); pushed_rdi = true; }

// We will consult the secondary-super array.
movptr(rdi, secondary_supers_addr);
// Load the array length.  (Positive movl does right thing on LP64.)
movl(rcx, Address(rdi, Array<Klass*>::length_offset_in_bytes()));
// Skip to start of data.
addptr(rdi, Array<Klass*>::base_offset_in_bytes());

// Scan RCX words at [RDI] for an occurrence of RAX.
// Set NZ/Z based on last compare.
// Z flag value will not be set by 'repne' if RCX == 0 since 'repne' does
// not change flags (only scas instruction which is repeated sets flags).
// Set Z = 0 (not equal) before 'repne' to indicate that class was not found.

testptr(rax,rax); // Set Z = 0
repne_scan();

// Unspill the temp. registers:
if (pushed_rdi)  pop(rdi);
if (pushed_rcx)  pop(rcx);
if (pushed_rax)  pop(rax);

if (set_cond_codes) {
  // Special hack for the AD files:  rdi is guaranteed non-zero.
  assert(!pushed_rdi, "rdi must be left non-NULL");
  // Also, the condition codes are properly set Z/NZ on succeed/failure.
}

if (L_failure == &L_fallthrough)
    jccb(Assembler::notEqual, *L_failure);
else  jcc(Assembler::notEqual, *L_failure);

// Success.  Cache the super we found and proceed in triumph.
movptr(super_cache_addr, super_klass);

if (L_success != &L_fallthrough) {
  jmp(*L_success);
}
...
```

Могу ошибаться, но это очень похоже на цикл с индексом *rdi*, где происходит итерация по массиву **_secondary_supers** из класса `Klass`.

Теперь можно подытожить. **JVM** пытается производить оптимизации, но в худшем случае мы имеем что `instanceof` будет выполняться линейно, пробегая по всей иерархии классов.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем корректный вопрос. `getClass()` делает не тоже самое, что и `instanceof`.

`getClass()` сравнивает лишь на конкретный класс, `instanceof` смотрит и подклассы.

```
class Animal {

}

class Dog extends Animal {

}


Object dog = new Dog();

System.out.println(dog instanceof Animal); // true
System.out.println(dog.getClass() == Animal.class); // false
```

А скорость у них почти одна и та же(в рамках погрешности), как минимум c Java 8.

Comment: Добавлю к вашему ответу, что конструкцию instanceof можно использовать не только с классами, но и с интефейсами.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что `instanceof` быстрее, поскольку это инструкция JVM, в отличие от `getClass()`, которая метод/функция, которая распадается еще на инструкции.

[Документация JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof)

Comment: что может быть быстрее сравнение двух ссылок? 
Вообщем мне кажется instanceOf будет медленнее, потому что он проверяет всю иерархию классов

Comment: `instanceof` проверяет таблицу организованную в виде `SparseBoolean`

Comment: угу, посмотри мой ответ